# builder = bookshelf.knex(tableNameOrBuilder);

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

i'm new with node.js and ORM's, and i'm using bookshelf for the db querys.
So, i checked the documentation of bookshelf and when i'm trying to build a query to my existing schema in mysql it throws the following error:

```
    TypeError: bookshelf.knex is not a function
        at Child.builderFn [as _builder] (/home/mauricio/techday/techday-            node/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:314:27)
at Object.query (/home/mauricio/techday/techday-node/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/helpers.js:44:23)
at Child.query (/home/mauricio/techday/techday-node/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1243:30)
at Function.Model.(anonymous function).Collection.(anonymous function) [as query] (/home/mauricio/techday/techday-node/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:333:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mauricio/techday/techday-node/app.js:20:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

here is my query:

```
    user
       .query('where', 'usuario', '=', 'admin')
       .fetch()
       .then(function(user) {
        console.log(user) 
    });
```

here is my db.js:

```
   'use strict'
       var db = require('bookshelf')(knex);
       var securePassword = require ('bookshelf-secure-password');
       db.plugin(securePassword);
       db.plugin('registry');


       var knex = require('knex')({
         client: 'mysql',
         connection: {
         host: 'localhost',
         user: 'root',
         password: 'password',
         database: 'test',
         charset: 'utf8'
       }
     });




       module.exports = db;
```

And now my user.js

```
var db = require('../Commons/db.js');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var user = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'usuario',
    hasSecurePassword: 'contraseña'
});



 module.exports = db.model('user',user);
```

Comment: How are `db` and `user` defined? Please add the code that defines both.

Comment: i already added both, user and db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of your connection must come before creating a bookshelf instance, so change your db.js to:

```
'use strict';
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'test',
    charset: 'utf8'
  }
});
var db = require('bookshelf')(knex); // now bookshelf knows how to connect
var securePassword = require('bookshelf-secure-password');
db.plugin(securePassword);
db.plugin('registry');

module.exports = db;
```

Anyway having the database connection explicitly placed on code is not recommended. For Knex based databases (like Bookshelf) a better approach should be to use a [knexfile](http://knexjs.org/#knexfile), so making easier to use knex CLI (migrations, seeds).

In this case your code would look like:

```
'use strict';
var knex = require('knex')(
  require('./knexfile')[process.env.NODE_ENV||'development']);
var db = require('bookshelf')(knex);
var securePassword = require('bookshelf-secure-password');
db.plugin(securePassword);
db.plugin('registry');

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about bookshelf, but at least one problem with your db.js code is that you are initializing bookshelf with `undefined` knex.

```
var db = require('bookshelf')(knex);
// knex is still undefined and will be initialized later on
// when you do var knex = require('knex')({...})
```

Error is not thrown there, because javascript `var`variables are hoisted to exist always from the start of the function even if they are uninitialized.

If you use `let`to declare variables, node will throw some unknown variable error when you try to initialize bookshelf.